# apple-touch-icon.png

Tags: apple-touch-icon

I can't get my iphone 4s to use the apple-touch-icon I made for the mobile site I am working on.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="150x150" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
```

That is in my header.

Comment: It shouldn't be in your header, it should be in your `<head>`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I'm sure he meant the `<head>` tag while writing 'header'...

Comment: And you have confirmed that the file is reachable? If your URL is `http://example.com/path/index.html` the image is in `http://example.com/path/apple-touch-icon.png`?

Comment: I did mean <head> and I fixed the issue. Thanks. For some reason, refresh wasn't working, but when I just typed the address in my bar again it worked.

Comment: minitech, the `<head>` section *is* for document headers (not the same as the transport headers in HTTP).

Comment: Complete answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385086/what-does-it-mean-when-the-apple-touch-icon-png-was-requested